# Validating multiple mongoose document and updating

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose, mongoose-schema

We have a mongoose model `Offer` and it has a field called `activatedDate` and `expirationDate`.

And in pre validate hook, I have my validation logic that throw error if `expirationDate` is less than `activatedDate`. (This is just an example, we have multiple fields which are being validated based on the record value of other field)

By doing this, I can validate and insert/update a single `Offer` document.
So far so good..

Now, we want to implement a new feature to multi-edit `Offer` model. So that our users don't have to update same field with same value one by one..

Keep in mind that we are expecting more than 10k Offers in system and theoretically. User can update all at once using this feature..

Is there a best way to update multiple mongoose document only after my validation is successful?

We can't do first lookup and then validate it one by one. It will take lot of time to do that.

Is there a optimal way to achieve this? 
It's OK if I have to change the way i am validating my model. I am open to any suggestions..

Answer (score 1):

**Idea 1**

I can suggest you to divide the problem in 2 parts:

First run the validation using some sort of [parallel queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-queue) to not run into memory problems.

And the second part to use the bulk update functionality.

```
const bulk = Offer.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
bulk.find(query).update(update);
bulk.execute(function (error) {
   callback(); // done                  
});
```

**Idea 2**

Use `streams`, mongoose support the `cursor` and streams and you can process safely all the rows from database, the memory use will be constant but the problem is it's not fast, it will iterate sequentially all your documents. Once I processed a 2M records collection with different operations and it took around 40 minutes, so definitely you can optimize things here.

```
 Offer
    .find()
    .cursor()
    .pipe(new Writable({
      objectMode: true,
      write(document, encoding, next) {
        // do your validation logic
        document.save(() => next());
      },
    }))
    .on('finish', () => {
      done();
    });
```

As an idea you can divide your collection in multiple streams and run them in parallel in this way you can gain a lot of time, but the trick is to sync all of them.